# How to overlay line plot over bar plot in r with secondary axis for 2 different datasets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay a line plot over a bar plot. I am using two different data sets, however. For the bar plot, I am using a table. For the line plot, I am using a regular data frame.

Using the code below, the line plot is not scaling correctly. Although I am coding for a secondary y-axis, it is still scaled according to the primary y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2);

a <- rep(seq(2015,2021),2);
b <- c(rep('x1',7), rep('x2',7));
c <- c(436, 1230, 1386, 1132, 1096, 756, 474, 24, 46, 110, 88, 66, 148, 96);

df_tab <- data.frame(year = a, lab = b, value=c);

df_prop <- data.frame(year=seq(2015,2021), value = df_tab$value[df_tab$lab=='x2']/df_tab$value[df_tab$lab=='x1'] );

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=df_tab, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=lab), stat="identity", position="identity", show.legend=FALSE)+
  geom_line(data=df_prop, aes(x=year, y=value), size=1.5, color="red")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./(2*max(df_tab$value)), name="proportion"))+
  geom_text(data=df_tab, aes(x=year, y=value, label=value), vjust=0.2, color="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=c("grey80","grey50"), aesthetics = 'fill', labels=c('X1','X2'))+
  labs(x="", y="frequency")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2015,2021, by=2))+
  theme_classic();
```

Any help is welcome, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept your code as it is, just changed `y` in `geom_line()`

```
ggplot()+
    geom_bar(data=df_tab, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=lab), stat="identity", position="identity", show.legend=FALSE)+
    geom_line(data=df_prop, aes(x=year, y=value*2*max(df_tab$value)), size=1.5, color="red")+
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./(2*max(df_tab$value)), name="proportion"))+
    geom_text(data=df_tab, aes(x=year, y=value, label=value), vjust=0.2, color="black")+
    scale_fill_manual(name="", values=c("grey80","grey50"), aesthetics = 'fill', labels=c('X1','X2'))+
    labs(x="", y="frequency")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2015,2021, by=2))+
    theme_classic();
```

You may want to change `2*max(df_tab$value)` to `3*max(df_tab$value)`, `4*max(df_tab$value)`, or `5*max(df_tab$value)` to check which is the preferred graph. When making such change, remember to change both values in `geom_line()` and `sec_axis()`.

[image]